# What is the font used for Sprite's logo (from 1994-2006)?

Tags: font-identification, logo

What is the font used in this logo? I tried many places and could not find a match

[image: Sprite logo circa 1994-2006]

Comment: I would say that a company of that size would probably not use a font for their logo, rather it is a set of glyphs created specifically for Sprite

Comment: i think it's a custom font exclusively for the company, hence finding external reference may return no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Crillee Italic** is the closest I could find.

[image: http://www.identifont.com/show?28Q]

If you haven't already, use: [identifont.com](http://identifont.com) and [What The Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to find fonts you're unsure of. It took some googling to find this one.

Comment: Yeah, Like @JohnB said, it's likely not a font, but a set of glyphs. This font, converted to outlines, might make it easier to recreate than making the shapes from scratch.